# Presentation of commutative group by integer matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abelian-groups, group-presentation

The task states: "Find a integer matrix $A \in Mat_{3 \times 4} \mathbb Z$ which presents commutative group $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_4$ and find it's Smith normal form". My thought is that SMT of such matrix should be $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
but I have trouble finding matrix itself. Am I right about SMT form? How do I find such a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix below is fine for $4$ generators
$$\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
but it's not in Smith normal form because we don't have $2 \mid 3 \mid 4$.

Since $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_4 \cong \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_{12}$, the Smith normal form will be
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 12 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Note that we now need only $3$ generators.

Comment: I don't have $A$ - it should be the size 3x4, not 4x4.

Comment: This can't be right. The theorem about SMT states that exist such invertible $P,Q$ for $A$, so that $P^{-1}AQ = S$, where $S$ is matrix in SMT. Because $A$ is 3x4, $Q$ must be 4x4, so $S$ must be also 4x4 matrix.

Comment: Scratch that, SMT should be in 3x4 form, because we are multiplying 3x3 x 3x4 x 4x4 matrices.